# How to grey out a gtkmm menu item that cannot be clicked on

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am using the library gtkmm in C++. This is the part of the code where I define "Open":

```
Gtk::ImageMenuItem *menuOpen = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ImageMenuItem(Gtk::Stock::OPEN));
menuFile->append(*menuOpen);
```

I want "Open" to be greyed out if I cannot click on it, but I don't know the method which allows to do that. Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In gtkmm 3 both `Gtk::ImageMenuItem` and `Gtk::Stock` have been deprecated, so it is best not to use them. Just use `Gtk::MenuItem` only with the text set to `"_Open"`.

All widgets in gtkmm derive from `Gtk::Widget`. The method to use is `Gtk::Widget::set_sensitive(bool)`.

To grey out or make insensitive your menu, use:

```
menuOpen->set_sensitive(false);
```

To re-enable the menu item:

```
menuOpen->set_sensitive();
```

If you want to find out if it is greyed out or not, use:

```
bool am_i_sensitive = menuOpen->get_sensitive();
```